# Use of atoi when string represents zero?

Tags: c++, g++, zero, atoi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if(argc != 2)
                return 1;
        if(!atoi(argv[1]))
                printf("Error.");
        else printf("Success.");
        return 0;
}
```

My code works when I enter an argument that is either below or above the value of zero.

```
[griffin@localhost programming]$ ./testx 1
Success.
[griffin@localhost programming]$ ./testx -1
Success.
[griffin@localhost programming]$ ./testx 0
Error.
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What about it doesn't work?  `(!0)` is true.  The only problem is that you've spelled "atoi returns 0" incorrectly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's very simple, `atoi` returns the number converted which in your case is exactly `0` (as expected).

There is no standard method of checking whether the conversion actually succeeded or not when using `atoi`.

Since you are writing c++ you could get the same result with better error checking by using a `std::istringstream`, `std::stoi` (C++11) or `strtol` (which is a better interface when dealing with arbitrary numbers).

---

**std::istringstream example**

```
#include <sstream>

  ...

std::istringstream iss (argv[1]);
int res;

if (!(iss >> res))
  std::cerr << "error";
```

---

**std::strtol example**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

  ...

char * end_ptr;

std::strtol (argv[1], &end_ptr, 10);

if ((end_ptr - argv[1]) != std::strlen (argv[1]))
  std::cerr << "error";
```

---

**std::stoi** (C++11)

```
#include <string>

  ...

int res;

try {
  res = std::stoi (argv[1]);

} catch (std::exception& e) {
  std::cerr << "error";
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I should've read the documentation a bit more thoroughly, feeling a bit stupid now. Up vote for a good alternative solution, and marked as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: There's also `stoi` in C++11, which will throw an exception.

Comment: @chris I'll update my answer with relevant information, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

Because `0` in C means `false` and any non-zero value means `true`. And `atoi("0")` returns 0, so the `if` statement branches to the `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) clearly states, that `atoi()` cannot detect errors. It always returns a number which in your case is `0`.

so your code evaluates to `if (!0)` which is true and therefor it falsely indicates an error.

There is no option to do error-handling with `atoi()` so you should use `strtoul()/strtol()` instead. (see manpage for example).